# What is it about kdb/q that makes the grammar not suitable for ANTLR style parser generators?

Tags: programming-languages, parsing, syntax, grammar

I want to build a code analysis tool for personal use when programming in kdb/q.
In order to do this, I need to be able to parse q code into an AST. I have never written a parser before. ANTLR4 seems to be a very mature, well documented tool so I thought it would be a good choice.

I found [this grammar](https://github.com/quintanar401/qll/blob/master/examples/ql.g) for a language which is similar to q, targeting a parser generator which is similar to ANTLR. However, I [asked the author](https://github.com/quintanar401/qll/issues/1) if this would be a good starting point to build an ANTLR4 grammar for q, and he said q grammar is not compatible with ANTLR style parser generators.

I would like some elaboration on this. If you (a potential responder to this question) are not familiar with q, then feel free to answer the more general question: what kinds of grammars are not suitable for ANTLR style parsers?

Comment: I have never heard of kdb/q so I don't know how its syntax works. Some syntax structures are inherently incompatible with ANTLR, since it uses a so-called `LL(*)` parsing approach whereas many languages are designed for the `PEG` or `LALR` algorithms. For example, a language where the meaning of input text depends on something that occurs later in the text are not a good fit for ANTLR, but can be easy for LR/LALR. And PEG has far more flexible lookaheads than LL(*) to resolve ambiguities. But maybe the author just meant that the grammar as written does not match the format expected by ANTLR.

Comment: Related https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/

Comment: It's not clear what the author meant. I imagine a right-associative grammar with no operator precedence would be able to parse APL-like languages.